# How to keep one record in specific column and make other record value 0 in group by clause in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, crystal-reports

I have a set of data like this

[image]

The Result should look Like this

[image]

My Query

```
SELECT max(pi.pi_serial) AS proforma_invoice_id,
       max(mo.manufacturing_order_master_id) AS manufacturing_order_master_id,
       max(pi.amount_in_local_currency) AS sales_value,
FROM proforma_invoice pi
JOIN schema_order_map som ON pi.pi_serial = som.pi_id
LEFT JOIN manufacturing_order_master mo ON som.mo_id = mo.manufacturing_order_master_id
WHERE to_date(pi.proforma_invoice_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') BETWEEN to_date('01/03/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND to_date('19/04/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
  AND pi.pi_serial in (9221,
                       9299)
GROUP BY mo.manufacturing_order_master_id,
         pi.pi_serial
ORDER BY pi.pi_serial
```

Comment: What is the problem with the current output? It should be expected that all rows in a group have the same `proforma_invoice.id` and `.sales_value`. How are you using the result data? Would you be open to a different format?

Comment: There is no problem with current output.. current output is fine, actually I am doing crystal report by using the data set. when I do summary of sales_value, the output i get is correct according to the query. but each proforma_invoice just contain one sales_value  in actual table. But according to the query the sales_value is being repeated. my current query is correct. but i need to somehow modify the query so that i get the expected output l(second image) which will solve my crystal report problem. Help me. if you know some way to solve this. bro @Bergi

Comment: I don't know crystal reports, maybe there's something like a rowspan feature? Otherwise I would suggest you either use two separate queries, or use something like `SELECT pi_serial AS proforma_invoice_id, amount_in_local_currency AS sales_value, (SELECT array_agg(mo_id) FROM schema_order_map WHERE pi_id = pi_serial) AS order_ids FROM proforma_invoice WHERE …`

Comment: Please do not post images. See [Why not Post Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67160537/how-to-keep-one-record-in-specific-column-and-make-other-record-value-0-in-group). A method of generating formatted text is using [Senseful Solutions](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/). Copy the resulting table and paste it into your question between 2 lines containing just ```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Create a "Running Total" field in Crystal Reports to sum up only one "sales_value" per "proforma_invoice_id".

Option 2: Add a helper column to your Postgresql query like so:

```
case 
    when row_number() 
         over (partition by proforma_invoice_id 
               order by manufacturing_order_master_id) 
         = 1 
then sales_value 
else 0 
end 
    as sales_value
```

I prepared [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/90963/10/0) with an example for you (and would of course like to encourage you to do the same for your next db query related question on SO, too :-)

Comment: Yap I already Solved It by using Row_number() after doing little bit research. i appreciate that you understand the problem.. bro.. thank you so much..